# Webserver with nginx working until .save file created

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

After googling everywhere the last 48 hours to find out why my server suddenly stopped working, and finally, finding the answer myself, I decided to post it up here for anyone else who is googling a whole weekend away on something so trivial.

Loaded everything on nginx, LEMP working perfectly, but then I tried to do some SSL modifications and in the middle of everything it stopped working.

I've completely removed everything but the necessary lines in **sites-available/www** (my version of sites-available/default) and checked that nginx.conf is correctly formatted without double includes that I've seen mentioned in other places.

It appears the a file sneaked into my configurations and messed everything up. It's an autosave file called **nginx.conf.save** which gets in the way of the original **nginx.conf** configuration and causes a *Page not found* error.

Now back to getting PHP working with SSL... happy times!

Comment: I had this issue due to editing an nginx config file with nano and then losing the terminal connection [as described here](http://askubuntu.com/a/295160/5271).

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with my LEMP stack that I'm running on a Digital Ocean droplet.I was working on the wordpress site all morning and then out of nowhere I got kicked out. Any advice on what I could do on Apache to fix my issue?

Answer (score 5):

Removed the file **nginx.conf.save** and reloaded nginx. Now it loads my webpages as it should.

Comment: I think that this file (nginx.conf.save) was created in directory which is included in nginx configuration, for example in Linux nginx.conf you have: include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

Comment: That's completely correct. That explains why it would try to load it as well, causing the whole server to stop working correctly. It also made a **www.save** version of my site in sites-availalbe or sites-enabled as you mentioned. I can't remember.

Comment: That's your editor at work as far as I can tell. This is why you should never edit files in sites-enabled but have only symlinks there pointing to sites-available. This may also be the reason that Ubuntu moved to include sites-enabled/*.conf instead of sites-enabled/*.