# Without changing settings I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED trying to reach my site

Tags: nginx, server-configuration

I have nginx running on my ubuntu 14.04 droplet, with one website at the moment. It was online and accessible until today, since I'm now getting a ERR CONNECTION REFUSED when I type in the url. It doesn't work on other devices/networks as well, but I can ping it...

Which lets me to believe there is suddenly something wrong with my configuration (although I haven't changed anything lately). Within my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file my settings are as followed:

```
   server  {
       listen 80;
       server_name paulvanmotman.com www.paulvanmotman.com;
       rewrite ^ https://www.$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/paulvanMotman;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
        expires 168h;
    }   

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    server_name paulvanmotman.com www.paulvanmotman.com;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate!

Kind regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem myself! For anyone who is interested, this was the problem I had: [Webserver with nginx working until .save file created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210115/webserver-with-nginx-working-until-save-file-created)

Comment: I'm having the same random error occur, no indication in the logs of anything going wrong, no configuration has changed. If I restart nginix, it's good for a week or so and then will randomly start throwing ERR CONNECTION REFUSED again. I looked for a .save file that might have been created by nano accidentally, but didn't find any. Any other suggestions?